# How to obtain boundary coordinates of binary mask with holes?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have the following image:

[image: test image]

I would like to obtain a list with `(x, y)`-coordinates of the outer and inner contour for each blob (let's call them blob A and B).

```
import cv2
from skimage import measure

blob = cv2.imread('blob.png', 0)
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(blob, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
labels = measure.label(blob)
props = measure.regionprops(labels)

for ii in range(0,len(props))
xy = props[ii].coords

plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16))
plt.imshow(blob, cmap='gray')
plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Desired output image where blue and red are drawn from the `(x, y)` coordinate list A and B:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: You could use morphological functions to get rid of the hole then find a bounding box for the outer boundary. Then use that to extract a patch from the (non-morphed) image and find the hole (you’ll need to add the patch coordinates back in afterwards).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the `(x, y)`-coordinates directly from [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). To identify the single blobs, have a look at the hierarchy `hier`. The fourth index tells you, to which outer (or parent) contour a possible inner (or child) contour is related. Most outer contours have an index of `-1`, all other have non-negative values. So, for plotting/drawing, a naive approach would be, while iterating the contours, to increase a blob counter every time you see a `-1`, and draw all contours with the same color until the next `-1` shows.

```py
import cv2
from skimage import io         # Only needed for web grabbing images, use cv2.imread for local images

# Read image; find contours with hierarchy
blob = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga5Pe.png')
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(blob, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Define sufficient enough colors for blobs
colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)]

# Draw all contours, and their children, with different colors
out = cv2.cvtColor(blob, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
k = -1
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    if (hier[0, i, 3] == -1):
        k += 1
    cv2.drawContours(out, [cnt], -1, colors[k], 2)

cv2.imshow('out', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Output]

Of course, obtaining all contours belonging to the same blob can be optimized using NumPy, but looping feels most intuitive here. I omitted all the other stuff (skimage, Matplotlib), since they didn't seem relevant here. As I said, the `(x, y)`-coordinates are already stored in `contours`.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** I haven't validated, if OpenCV always obtains all contours belonging to one most outer contour continously, or if - for example - all contours for a given hierarchy level are stored subsequently. So, for more complicated hierarchies, this should be tested beforehand, or the mentioned index finding using NumPy should be used right from the start.

Comment: I tried to modify your code but got some issues during a loop. I tried to draw the blue and green objects in separate images. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: @ChristineP That pretty much sounds like a new question. So, please don't hesitate and ask another question, and describe your problem there, including your (modified) code. For context and reference, you can link to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970920/python-find-contour-of-multiple-objects-with-their-holes